# WooCommerce Out of Stock Message

Tags: woocommerce

This is weird, but how can I only show the stock status on products that are virtual in the woocommerce store?  Products not marked as virtual I want to hide the stock status.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your theme's function.php or in a plugin to display the stock only on products that are virtual and not on others.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_stock_html", "dont_display_stock_non_virtual");
function dont_display_stock_non_virtual($display, $availability){
    global $product;
    if( !$product->is_virtual() )
        return "";
    return $display;
}
```

P.S. - This code will not get affected if you update your WooCommerce.